# subsection command not working in elsevier LaTeX template

Tags: sectioning, formatting, els-cas

I am working on Elsevier template with a single column format, I am facing an issue with subsections command not working as they are displayed like a normal section with wrong numbering, for example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}
\begin{document}
\section{A}
\subsection{AA}
\subsubsection{BB}
\end{document}
```

[image: The output is like this. All sections with no subsection numbering.]

Can anyone help me on how to fix this issue?

Comment: @campa sorry, I could not understand your response. What is correct?

Comment: @campa I just googled it (after commenting) and found it. Would you look at that, Elsevier switched to `expl3` :). Well, then I think this is the expected behaviour...

Comment: campa replied to a comment I deleted, so it looked out of context.

Comment: Okay, what is the final situation now?

Comment: Your example is minimal and there is nothing wrong with it, so it's not your fault. I think you'd need to contact the Elsevier support and ask it there. There are two possibilities: 1) This is a design choice and you have to live with it. 2) It's a bug and they need to fix it (looks more like it). Either way, only they know the answer, unfortunately.

Comment: Okay, I will get in touch with Elsevier. Btw, it should not be a design choice as the subsection should always be a 1.1 and not 2 and subsubsection should be 1.1.1 and not 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, definitely a bug :)

The definition of `\section`, `\subsection`, and `\subsubsection` in `cas-common.sty` uses the same counter, `section`, for all three levels. (*i.e.:* `\@startsection{section}...`). If you copy that definition and use the correct counters the output looks correct:

> [image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
    {15pt \@plus 3\p@ \@minus 3\p@}%
    {4\p@}%
    {%\let\@hangfrom\relax
     \sectionfont\raggedright\hst[13pt]}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
    {10pt \@plus 3\p@ \@minus 2\p@}%
    {.1\p@}%
    {%\let\@hangfrom\relax
     \ssectionfont\raggedright }}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
    {10pt \@plus 1\p@ \@minus .3\p@}%
    {.1\p@}%
    {%\let\@hangfrom\relax
     \sssectionfont\raggedright}}
\makeatother

\section{A}
\subsection{AA}
\subsubsection{BB}

\end{document}
```